# I cannot call an android function from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I just started make a kind of Android hybrid app, an application with WebView. As a first step, I tried to call a function of Android code from JavaScript. But, the app keeps crashing while I am at it.

All I did was setting up WebView, adding a class that is used from JavaScript code, then calling the function from JavasScript.

Thanks in advance.

The android codes are following:

```
public class Grand_ride_androidActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
...
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        mWebView.loadUrl(Config.url);
    }
}

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public void ensureTracking(Integer rideId) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

And the HTML is following:

```
...
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        Android.ensureTracking(97);
//]]>
</script><div>
        <p>You have checked in at 03:44PM</p>
        <a href="/rides/97/check_out">Check out</a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey , i am having some problem with the java script call back. I tried your way but something is not working, can you please check once , Thank you in advance.Here is the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243686/android-callback-function-from-java-script-to-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can only use primitive types and String, so ensureTracking(Integer rideId) should be ensureTracking(int rideId).