# Android : callback function from java script to java

Tags: java, javascript, android

I have created an application in which i am using webview and loading a simple static html page. I am calling a java script function from activity but i am unable to call a function from java script. I have tried few of the link , but it didn't work . 
[Javascript Callback function pass to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019265/javascript-callback-function-pass-to-android)
[I cannot call an android function from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636118/i-cannot-call-an-android-function-from-javascript?rq=1)

Here is my code. Thank you in advance.

acitivity_main.xml

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call JavaScript Function"
        android:onClick="callJavaScript" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function displayMessage(){
            document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = 'This is from java script.';
            Android.returnResult();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="test1">Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Main activity has following two functions .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptHandler(this), "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    public void callJavaScript(View view) {
        Log.v(null, "Calling java Script");
        myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayMessage()");
    }
```

This is the JavaScriptHandler class

```
public class JavaScriptHandler {
    Context mContext;

    public JavaScriptHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void returnResult() {
        Log.v(null, "result received");
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly add alert statements in your javascript method to see if you javascript method is getting called properly. Otherwise I dont see any problem in your implementation.

Comment: Thank you for replying , i have added a line to change the html text when java script is getting called and it was working anyway i got the  answer looks like i had to use the annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void returnResult() {
    Log.v(null, "result received");
}
```

This annotation allows exposing methods to JavaScript.